# Bash Redirecting Output From Multiple Functions to A File

Tags: bash, file, function, redirect, output

I am trying to make a script that will redirect some output from a couple of functions to a file. Here is what my code looks like.

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /var/log/test.log
results=/var/log/test.log

outputFormat()
{
    echo "This is outputFormat" >> results
}

outputParseFull()
{

    echo "This is outputParseFull" >> results
    outputFormat;
}

outputParseFull;
```

After running this, /var/log/test.log is created but the file itself is blank. I want the file to contain the following

**This is outputParseFull**

**This is outputFormat**

One line must be from each function. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing to a file named `results`, not using the filename in the variable `$results`.

```
echo "This is outputParseFulll" >> results
```

should be

```
echo "This is outputParseFulll" >> $results
```

Answer (score 1):

1.), when using an variable, you should to use `$results` instead of the plain `results`.

2.), you can short your script, redirecting the output from the function, like:

```
results="./file"
touch "$results"

outputFormat() {
    echo "This is outputFormat"
}

outputParseFull() {
    echo "This is outputParseFull"
    outputFormat;
}

outputParseFull >"$results"
```

3.) Always quote filenames, like `"$filename"`. (because, they can contain spaces)

Comment: +1 An obscure corner of `bash` syntax is that you can also apply output redirection to the definition of a function: `outputParseFull () { ...; } > "$results"`. This redirects the standard output of the function for each call (that is, each call would overwrite the contents of the file; use `>> "$results"` to append to the file each time the function is called).

Comment: @chepner - WOW - This is new for me. Going to read about it. THANX! ;)